# What verb can I use when someone tries to speak while being throttled?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What verb can I use when someone speaks while being throttled?

Let's say Peter is throttling Mark, who says something through a constricted throat.
I was thinking of "grate". An [ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grated%20out%2Crasped%20out&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrated%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crasped%20out%3B%2Cc0) gave me some results with the expression "grated out".

So, for example, can I say,

> 'Stop it!' Mark grated out.

I also thought of the verb "rasp", but to my ear, it doesn't seem to convey this specific meaning I'm looking for.

Comment: I would not understand what *grated out* meant.  I don't know a specific word that meets your requirement.  *Sputtered* might be close.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian. The freedicitonary gives this definition of grate: 2. To cause to make a harsh grinding or rasping sound through friction: grated her teeth in anger. So, I thought, if a person can grate their teeth, why not words?

Comment: I've never heard the verb 'grate' used that way, though from the first [handful](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22grated%20out%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2017,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) of books I looked at from your NGram result, it does seem to be used that way sometimes. It isn't in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grate) or [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/grate) dictionaries.

Comment: It's the **sound** that seems grated: like something being grated on a grater. "'Hello,'" he grated" doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @Fra: [Sorry - I was re-writing my comment when you wrote yours.] Yes, we can grate our **teeth**. But I don't think we can grate out "Hello". You can grind out a tune, because that's what hurdy-gurdies did, but I've never heard anyone grind out "Stop it!". Mark can say "Stop it" **in a grating voice**, but I wouldn't make him grate out "Stop it". Some writers use it, so - it's your choice. I'm in the UK btw: maybe it's different where you are :) ...

Comment: ... Or he could wheeze, gasp, hiss, croak, squeal, squeak...? Or maybe: _"Stop it!" he **[rasped](https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/rasp)**, his voice grating like rusty wheels._

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - you see 'grated' in bad novels (or you used to). Grated 2 [transitive] (written) to talk in a low rough voice  **‘Let me go, ’ he grated harshly**. Longmans Dictionary

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - re bad novels - "I walk in the Light,” he grated hoarsely, “and you can never touch me!”' Seems to be somewhere between a croak and a rasp?

Comment: If utterances can be croaked, wheezed, or rapped out, I don't see why they can't be grated out. Whether it is appropriate (or possible) for someone who is being strangled, I don't pretend to judge. Nor whether it is elegant.

Comment: It's not that "he grated" is *wrong*, it just doesn't really match what the OP wants.  It means "to speak with a grating tone", but doesn't imply "while being throttled".

Comment: @Michael Harvey: Ah! So it **is** in a dictionary. I only looked looked at two. Re bad novels: Yes, between croak and rasp, I reckon. I remember enjoying a Barbara Cartland that was quite similar to the OP's: "He took her in his arms and strained her to him."

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - ' but I've never heard anyone grind out "Stop it!". ' - then you haven't lived!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "grated" to "blubbered" and it would be spot on, I feel certain. One dictionary defines "blubber out" as "utter while crying". I have heard it used to mean utter incoherently or whilst under stress or duress.

[Update] But after rereading the question, I realize that I had the meaning of "throttle" wrong. In that case I believe that ""Mark croaked out" is appropriate. Don't you?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use "**gurgle**".

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gurgle):

> **gurgle** verb
> **2 :** to make a sound like that of a gurgling liquid
> *// the baby gurgling in his crib*

This verb suggests some kind of restriction, and if Hollywood is to be believed, that's the sound people make when they're being choked.